# how to pass a reference to a variable between function components?

Tags: reactjs

I have this component that I use to only show a `select` element when a condition is met in another component. (it looks something like `userIsAdmin ? <thisComponent/> : null`)

I have a variable which I export as `adminSelectBase` which is the selected option. Is there instead another way to pass either a state variable (from `useState`) or just some data from the child *to* the parent?

alternatively, could I somehow pass a *reference* of a state or variable to the child component? something like: `<thisComponent myVariable={variable} setMyVariable={setMyVariable}/>`?

```
import React from 'react';
import "./createinquiry.css";

export let adminSelectBase = false;

export default function AdminBaseSelectComponent(props) {

    return (
        <>
            <select className="Create-Inquiry-input" onChange={(e) => adminSelectBase = e.target.value}>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
                <option value="22">22</option>
                <option value="25">25</option>
                <option value="28">28</option>
                <option value="30">30</option> 
            </select><br/>
        </>
    )
}
```

EDIT:
usage of this component:
`{isAdmin ? <AdminBaseSelectComponent/> : null}`

this select component changes a stateful variable:
`[selectedBase, setSelectedBase] = useState("");`

Comment: If you need to send data ***up*** the React tree, from child to parent, then the parent should pass a callback function as a prop to the child for the child to invoke. It is a common pattern to [lift state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) to a common ancestor and pass the state and state updater functions down to children.

Comment: Could you possibly give an example in an answer? it makes sense but I am having a hard time making it into code.

Comment: Sure, but can you first provide an example of the two components you are trying to pass props/values between?

Comment: Hi, I've edited the question to provide the exact definitions. Basically this select controls a variable which I later send to a database, and is automatically selected if the user is not an admin by my program.